# Bootstrap select hides after selecting option

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am facing an issue regarding bootstrap select. Below is my code

```
<pre>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Issue Items to:</label>                               
   <div class="col-md-4">                                                       
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control selectpicker" data-
      live-search="true" ID="ddlIssueItems" ClientIDMode="Inherit" 
      AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvIssueItemsto" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlIssueItems" InitialValue=0 ErrorMessage="Required!">
     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                                   </div>
</div>
</pre>
```

The Above code display the dropdownlist with live search. When i select option from list the whole dropdownlist disappear or hide.
Please help me.
Thanks